# Podio: Get Items with tasks

Tags: podio

I am trying to retrieve Tasks associated with an Item using the .Net API, but the List in Item is always null. I'm using app authentification

```
var item = Podio.ItemService.GetItem(podioGlobalId, false);
            if (item.Tasks == null)
            {
                //there are never any Tasks
            }
```

Comment: We want facts, not a fairy tail. Read [mcve] and [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tasks are independent and connected to items but are not part of item. So, in order to get list of tasks that are attached to item(s) please use `get tasks` method. Documentation for it is here: https://developers.podio.com/doc/tasks/get-tasks-77949.

Example of usage from raw http request:

```
GET https://api.podio.com/task/?reference=item:1234;item:5678
```

Comment: Thanks Pavlo. I was just confused as to why they are even in the Item class in the API in that case.